# Is there an smart way to write a fixed length flat file using camel and smooks

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, smooks, fixed-length-record

Is there any framework/library to help writing fixed length flat files in java?

I want to write a collection of beans/entities into a flat file without worrying with convertions, padding, alignment, fillers, etcs

For example, I'd like to parse a bean like:

```
public class Entity{
    String name = "name"; // length = 10; align left; fill with spaces
    Integer id = 123; // length = 5; align left; fill with spaces
    Integer serial = 321 // length = 5; align to right; fill with '0'
    Date register = new Date();// length = 8; convert to yyyyMMdd
}
```

**Into Flatfile**

```
Jaya       123 0032120110505
Prathiksha5000 0122120110504
Prabha       1 0000120101231
...
```

[Smooks Fixed length](http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=V1.5%3aSmooks_v1.5_User_Guide#Fixed_Length_Values) using this i can able to read the file as POJO, List or Map.

The issue is i am unable to find any process to write POJO to FixedLenthFile.

Also kindly suggest is there any other way to process the FixedLengthFlatFIle using camel,spring Project.

Currently in our project we are using smooks, camel, spring for EDI to POJO and POJO to EDI. Now we have to add features for FixedLengthFlatFile Processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

WRT [link](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Is-there-an-smart-way-to-write-a-fixed-length-flat-file-td5743323.html)

bindy or beanio which can work with flat files

[Camel Bindy](http://camel.apache.org/bindy)

[Camel Beanio](http://camel.apache.org/beanio)

Smooks doesn't work with Camel 2.10 onwards (AFAIR). There is a ticket 
reported to the smooks team to fix that, but they haven't done it yet, 
not released a new version of Smooks in a fairly long time. I would 
try to avoid using Smooks, until the project comes back to life (if it 
does).

Comment: In Camel in Action, 2nd edition, it says "Two of the existing CSV-related data formats (camel-csv and camel-flatpack) are older libraries that don’t take advantage of the new features in Java 1.5, such as annotations and generics. In light of this deficiency, Charles Moulliard stepped up and wrote the camel-bindy component to take advantage of these new possibilities. It’s capable of binding CSV, FIX, and fixed-length formats to existing model objects using annotations. This is similar to what JAXB does for XML."